# low-dim unitary groups and their actions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, group-actions, homogeneous-spaces

I need someone to explain for me the unitary groups $U(1)$, $U(2)$ and $U(3)$ and their actions: Specifically:

- $U(3)/U(2)$
- $U(3)/U(2)\times U(1)$
- $U(3)/U(1)\times U(1) \times U(1)$

I have seen somewhere that $U(3)/U(2)\times U(1)=\mathbb CP^2$ but I don't know the proof! If it is so, and if $\mathbb CP^1= \mathbb C^1 \sqcup \{\infty\}$, then can we write the set $U(3)/U(1)\times U(1) \times U(1)$ in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of all three homogeneous spaces can be derived from the standard linear action of $U(3)$ on $\mathbb C^3$. Since unitary maps preserve the lenght of vectors, this restricts to a transitive action on the Unit sphere in $\mathbb C^3$ which is $S^5$. The stabilizer of a point in $S^5$ is easily seen to be isomorphic to $U(2)$, whence $U(3)/U(2)\cong S^5$.

The linear action also induces a transitive actions of $U(3)$ on the space $\mathbb CP^2$ of 1-dimensional complex subspaces in $\mathbb C^3$, and the stabilizer of such a subspace is isomorphic to $U(2)\times U(1)$. (The factor $U(2)$ is the stabilizer of a unit vector in that line as above and the $U(1)$-factor comex from the fact that you can form complex multiples of that vector). This gives the isomorphism $U(3)/(U(2)\times U(1))$ with $\mathbb CP^2$ that you mention. In the same way, you can identify $U(3)/(U(2)\times U(1))$ with the space of two dimensional complex subspaces of $\mathbb C^3$.

Finally, $U(3)$ also acts transitively on the space of all flags consisting of a 1-dimensional complex subspace cotained in a 2-dimensional complex subspace of $\mathbb C^3$. The stabilizer of such a flag is isomorphic to $U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)$, whence the last homogeneous space can be identified with the space of all such flags.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! Is it possible to write $U(3)/U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1) $ as something like $\mathbb C^2\sqcup \mathbb C^1 \sqcup ...$?

Comment: There is a decomposition of the flag manifold into so-called Schubert-cells which are isomorphic to $\mathbb C^k$ for different $k$, but this is a slightly involved story. You get one cell in dimension 3, two cells in dimension 2, two in dimension 1 and one point.

Comment: Oh! That's what I am looking for actually? Can you kindly provide me with the " Shubert-cells" for the full flag($\mathbb C^3$)? If you like I can ask an individual question about it and you write the solution - if you have the time and desire for that- I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: Or at least if you know some introductory notes which discuss this flag ?!

Comment: The decomposition into Schubert cells is usually described using quite a bit of structure theory for Lie groups, but I think I can give an elementary description for that case. This will be too long for a comment, so it is better if you pose a separate question on the Schubert cell decomposition of the full flag manifold of $\mathbb C^3$.

Comment: Oh man, very nice! I have posted a question about that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545901/schubert-cell-decomposition-and-full-flags  I am looking forward to seeing your answer ... Thank you so much